# Что использовать otto или broadcastreceiver?

Tags: android, otto

На днях изучил библиотеку otto,  она очень похоже на broadcastreceiver, в моей проекте я получаю из service данный и отправляю в  fragment, Что посоветуете использовать otto или broadcastreceiver?  через otto  более чистый код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otto лучше broadcastreceiver. В своё время перешёл на Otto с ресивера и только рад этому.

C другой стороны создатели Otto сами говорят об устарелости своей библиотеки и призывают переходить на RxAndroid.

Comment: Впервые слышу про удаление или запрещение `BroadcastReceiver`. Можно источник?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, чётко помню, что читал что-то такое когда анонсировали новую версию, но сейчас нагуглить ничего не смог... 0_о

Comment: Там что-то было, что доставка системных событий меняется, но не сам `BroadcastReceiver` как таковой. Свои собственные события будут бегать как и прежде.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, ну, видимо я что-то не так тогда понял) Из ответа это убрал)

Comment: Вот тут хорошо расписано, может кому понадобится :) http://www.r-bricks.com/2016/04/android-n-3-implicit-broadcast-removed.html

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, что бы получить чистый код, не нужно использовать ничего из перечисленного, подобные басы - это как `goto`, можно сделать все что хочешь, напрочь запутав код.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем конкретном случае я бы посоветовал `binding service`. Фрагмент прекрасно подключается-отключается к сервису согласно жизненного цикла, а сервис всем подключенным раздает данные. И никаких сторонних библиотек.